# How can I build a risk matrix in databse tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'd like to build a risk matrix in a SQL database.  A very basic one looks like so:

```
------------------------------------
|          |Consequence            |
|Likelihood|Low    |Medium |High   |
|Low       |Level 1|Level 1|Level 2|
|Medium    |Level 1|Level 2|Level 3|
|High      |Level 2|Level 3|Level 4|
------------------------------------
```

My current ERD looks like this:

[image: database risk matrix draft]

I will have a software program that will read from another table (it exists out of frame immediately to the left of that screenshot).  This other table contains values for likelihood and consequence associated with a particular entry in that table.  The program will then query the risk matrix and return a risk level (eg. Having likelihood = Low and consequence = High would return a risk level = Level 1).

As you can see in the diagram, on the risk matrix table I have foreign keys linking likelihoodid and consequenceid to their respective tables.  I also have a composite primary key across likelihoodid and consequenceid.  Currently there is a composite unique key across likelihoodid and consequenceid also because some research I did suggested I needed this, but it seems wrong to me.

Is this design OK, completely wrong, or needs some tweaking?

**Edit**

DDL as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likelihoods` (
  `likelihoodid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longname` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`likelihoodid`)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consequences` (
  `consequenceid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longname` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`consequenceid`)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `riskmatrix` (
  `likelihoodid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `consequenceid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `levelid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`likelihoodid`,`consequenceid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_likelihoodid_consequenceid` (`likelihoodid`,`consequenceid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_consequences` (`consequenceid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_risklevels` (`levelid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_likelihoods` (`likelihoodid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_consequences` FOREIGN KEY (`consequenceid`) REFERENCES `consequences` (`consequenceid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_likelihoods` FOREIGN KEY (`likelihoodid`) REFERENCES `likelihoods` (`likelihoodid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_risklevels` FOREIGN KEY (`levelid`) REFERENCES `risklevels` (`levelid`)
```

Comment: Your design looks ok to me, what is it that you find wrong with the composite key?

Comment: Just that having a composite primary key and a composite unique key on the same two fields seems redundant.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that is redundant since they are the same at the logical level (as constraints). However, at the physical level (as indexes) they are not the same so there may be reasons to add an index with the column order of your unique constraint. I suggest you wait with that until there is a performance need for it.

Comment: I may be blind, but I don't see a key for riskmatrix in the image. Should there not be a little key-symbol in front of likelihoodid and consequences?

Comment: @Lennart thanks for the feedback.  The key is definitely there - I normally work in HeidiSQL and I can see it in the GUI and in the ‘’’create’’’ statement.  I imported this db into a model in MySQL Workbench just to generate the diagram.  Maybe the workbench doesn’t handle icons for composite keys very well?

Comment: If you have ddl, it is much better to post that, than images

Comment: @Lennart OK I'll keep that in mind in future.  I've updated it with DDL now.

Comment: UK_likelihoodid_consequenceid is definitely redundant since it even have the same column order.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`.  That `UNIQUE KEY` is redundant and should be `DROPped`.

Comment: @RickJames thanks I’ve got that fixed up in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK based on @Lennart's feedback, this is a pretty good design for a risk matrix in a database, to suit my needs as described in the question.  I've removed the Unique Key, which was duplicating the Primary Key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likelihoods` (
  `likelihoodid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longname` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`likelihoodid`)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consequences` (
  `consequenceid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longname` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`consequenceid`)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `riskmatrix` (
  `likelihoodid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `consequenceid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `levelid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`likelihoodid`,`consequenceid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_consequences` (`consequenceid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_risklevels` (`levelid`),
  KEY `FK_riskmatrix_likelihoods` (`likelihoodid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_consequences` FOREIGN KEY (`consequenceid`) REFERENCES `consequences` (`consequenceid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_likelihoods` FOREIGN KEY (`likelihoodid`) REFERENCES `likelihoods` (`likelihoodid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_riskmatrix_risklevels` FOREIGN KEY (`levelid`) REFERENCES `risklevels` (`levelid`)
```